# Simple .ajax fail

Tags: jquery

A simple fiddle where .ajax fails:

```
<form action="welcome_post.php" method="post" id="f">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#f").submit(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $.post("/tests/welcome_post.php",function(data){
              alert(data)
          }); 
      }); 
  });
</script>
```

and welcome_post.php response

```
<?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>
```

If I remove event.preventDefault() the code loads a new php page and works, otherwise the $_POST variable is not set and alerts with undefined index error. How to make it set for .post to work?

Comment: I don't see your data sent to request.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['name']))` ...?

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because you do not send POST data actually.

This should work:

```
jQuery('#f').submit(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var data = jQuery(this).serialize();
    jQuery.post('your/url.php', data, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't sending any data in your request. Because it's ajax, you have to tell it what data to use. It doesn't automatically use the form data, you have to specify it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#f").submit(function(event) {        
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post(
     "/tests/welcome_post.php",
     $(this).serialize(), //this will serialise the form data into the request
     function(data){
      alert(data);
     }
    ); 
  }); 
});
```

See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ for the full list of parameters you can submit using this method.

Also, you should use the Network tab of your browser's Developer Tools to monitor the contents of your requests and responses - this will help you understand the root causes of issues like this.

Comment: @Adam did any of the the answers help you at all? If so please consider upvoting / marking as the accepted answer - thanks :-)